# Should convert simple math into HTML tag and complex math into MathML

Tags: tex4ht

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
This is for test $a+b=c^2$ also test $\sqrt{a+b=c^2}$
\end{document}
```

While converting the above code using `TeX4ht` through the command line as `htlatex test "xhtml,mathml" " -cunihft" "-cvalidate -p"` then it converts the entire math into MathML format, but my expectation is simple math should be in `HTML` tag, and complex math should be in `MathML`, e.g.,

`$a+b=c^2$` should convert in HTML tags, i.e.,

```
class="cmmi-10">a </span>+ <span 
class="cmmi-10">b </span>= <span 
class="cmmi-10">c</span><sup><span 
class="cmr-7">2</span></sup>
```

and `$\sqrt{a+b=c^2}$` should convert in `MathML` format, i.e.,

```
<math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="inline" ><msqrt><mrow><mi 
>a</mi> <mo 
class="MathClass-bin">+</mo> <mi 
>b</mi> <mo 
class="MathClass-rel">=</mo> <msup><mrow 
><mi 
>c</mi></mrow><mrow 
><mn>2</mn></mrow></msup 
></mrow></msqrt></math>
```

Please advise how to achieve this....

Comment: I am sure you could configure tex4ht to do that (it can be configured in lots of ways) but why do that? If you are showing display matgh as mathml yiu are assuming mathml rendering so what is the downside of using it for inline math as well. Otherwise you will be using different fonts and spacing for inline math v display math which will never look good

Comment: I am afraid that it would be extremely difficult to configure TeX4ht for simple math and MathML at the same time. It could be possible to convert all inline math to images, but it is not something that I would recommend. Other possibility would be to post-process inline MathML and convert it to a simpler HTML (for example MathJax cli could be used)